# Is autogenerated constraint name in SQL Server same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I am currently working on one project in which I want to drop some foreign key constraint on columns. But the tragedy is all constraint are generated by Hibernate itself. I have dump of an old database.

So my question is: can I use my database's constraint name in a script which I am going to provide to client?

Because it will depend on the name of constraint. If autogenerated names are same then there is no issue. So can I be sure that my database's constraint will match client database's constraints?

Comment: No, I wouldn't bet my farm on this. If you need to know the constraint's name, **name them explicitly** yourself.

Comment: @marc_s: I didn't know you have farm...

Comment: @RemusRusanu: there's a lot you don't know about me :-)

Comment: @marc_s Yea I know this is not a good practice. But is auto generated names are same? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from one blog. Here is the link http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1570801/Beware-of-the-System-Generated-Constraint-Name.htm

Short summary: System generated constraint name can be different so if you want to refer it in script, explicitly provide names to constraint and use it later on.

Comment: The link contains useful information! But you should at least give a summary of it in your answer (while still hyperlinking the reference, of course).

Comment: Thank you @JeppeStigNielsen I've updated my answer with short summary from link.

Comment: In practice, it is always different.